# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_loc'. Did you mean: 'iloc'? | PyCharm

Tags: python, pandas

Unfortunately this code doesn't work for me in PyCharm:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': ['Jai', 'Princi', 'Gaurav', 'Anuj'], 'Age': [27, 24, 22, 32],
        'Address': ['Delhi', 'Kanpur', 'Allahabad', 'Kannauj'], 'Qualification': ['Msc', 'MA', 'MCA', 'Phd']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.loc[0, :]
```

Could you please help?

Tried to update Pandas

Comment: The provided code works fine for me

Comment: working fine on my side..!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`print(df.loc[0, :])`

instead of

`df.loc[0, :]`

although it working fine on my pycharm..

[image]